# Toggle between two images in a long list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long list (dynamically created) that can contain only one of two images; red.png or green.png and look like this:

```
<img src="red.img" id="choice1" onclick=" changeIcon('1')">
<img src="red.img" id="choice2" onclick=" changeIcon('2')">
...
<img src="red.img" id="choiceN" onclick=" changeIcon('N')">
```

I manage to toggle between red and green by using the following java script:

```
function changeIcon(line){

    var l = "choice".concat(line);

            if (document.getElementById(l).src == "red.png") 
            {document.getElementById(l).src = "green.png";
            }else {
              document.getElementById(l).src = "red.png";
            }
}
```

What I am trying to do  is that when I click on the red image only this (id?) become green and the rest of the list become red and if I click on a green then this become back to red so the entire list is red again.
The concept is similar to the radio buttons but without using form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, try using:

```
var l = "choice" + line;
```

Or, even better, I would suggest you to change your code this way, using jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
  // Replace "body" with some static parent of "img.toggle".
  $("body").on("click", ".toggle", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == "red.img")
      this.src = "green.img";
    else
      this.src = "red.img";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you want it to act like a **radio button**, you can use this:

```js
$(function () {
  // Replace "body" with some static parent of "img.toggle".
  $("body").on("click", ".toggle", function () {
    // Reset everything.
    $(".toggle").attr("src", "red.img");
    this.src = "green.img";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
<img src="red.img" class="toggle" />
```

The same thing can be achieved without using images:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".radios").on("click", "span", function () {
    $(".radios span").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.radios span {display: inline-block; width: 12px; height: 12px; border: 1px solid #999; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 100%;}
.radios span.active {border-color: #000; background-color: #666;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only toggle a single item to be green, the rest of the list is also changes.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It changes only the image that is clicked.

Comment: Exactly: *"this (id?) become green and the **rest of the list become red**"*

Comment: Last note is that in the second snippet you would want to check if the item clicked is `red.png`. Err, but it would be the nearly the same as my answer when. It might not be necessary to get the OP to see the concept of what to do.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, let's wait for the OP to respond. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To change all the items at once add a class to your images (I'll use a class named `img` as an example):

```
<img src="red.png" class="img" id="choice1" onclick=" changeIcon('1')">
<img src="red.png" class="img"  id="choice2" onclick=" changeIcon('2')">
...
<img src="red.png" class="img"  id="choiceN" onclick=" changeIcon('N')">
```

Then when you trigger the event change them all to a certain color, and then `this` to the desired color. Below is an example of when clicking a "red" item, changing the item clicked to green and the rest to red:

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    if( $(this).attr('src') == "red.png" ) {
        $(".img").attr('src', "red.png"); // Make them all red
        $(this).attr('src', "green.png"); // Change the clicked one to green
    }
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydsn8se1/) (Note you will need to look at the src of the images directly to see the changes)

Answer (score 0):

just use **class** attribute to change whole list to red then **this** to toggle clicked item

```
    //the jQuery function
    function toggleSrc()
    {
        var nextSrc = "red.png";

        if( $(this).attr("src") == "red.png" )
            nextSrc = "green.png";

        $(".image").attr("src","red.jpg");
        $(this).attr("src",nextSrc);
    }

    //binding function to .image
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".image").click( toggleSrc );
    });

    //and the HTML:
    <img src="red.png" class="image" id="choice1">
    <img src="red.png" class="image" id="choice2">
```